# Chrome download window stuck at full screen

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

I upgraded to 22.04 the other week and have been stuck with a weird chrome behavior. Whenever I try to download something (say, by right-clicking and choosing "save link as") the "save as" window that pops up is full screen. And I haven't spotted any way to resize.

If I try to move this window with click-and-drag, it actually moves the (hidden) browser, not the "save as" window.

Any/all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  This is really annoying on large monitors.

Comment: That Window is an Ubuntu Window (where you can save as) and that window can be resized in the way you want and will be remembered by the Ubuntu OS. I don't know when you reboot if that window-size you've choosen will be remembered. But you can resize that pop-up window in the size you want (select the edge, top, bottom for resizing).

Comment: For me, it does not resize when I do any of the following:
- Try to drag a corner
- Keyboard shortcut for window "toggle maximization state"
- Log out/in
- Reboot

After all of these actions, it remains maximized.

Answer (score 1):

try to right click on that window title and choose resize and now you can resize it manually

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I resized this way, but the problem returns: Every time I choose a download location, the download window gets bigger, eventually covering the entire screen again.